# How do I allow international character set?

Tags: java, utf-8, utf

How do I allow international character set in my application? Basically include all asian characters etc.

Comment: This was not a REST related question. Please edit your answer with the details of your architecture. What HTTP framework you use etc...

Answer (score 0):

Output in a Unicode representation. Like UTF-8. Mixed with latin script (like XML/HTML/JSON) it is even more compact with Asian scripts than UTF-16LE/BE. The database definition should use UTF-8 too.

A desktop application should consider the need of a Unicode font or several substituted fonts (like Asian/Cyrillic font in browser). Asian script needs a larger size. If you provide pre-printed paperwork: the paper has to be of a better quality.

Right-To-Left scripts in the GUI might need an RTL layout too. Swing has support for that.

As UTF-8 is an encoding guaranteed to be present in every JRE (in contrast to some other encodings), you can use the Charset constant:

```
StandardCharsets.UTF_8
```

Set the source (editor) encoding to UTF-8, and the javac compiler too.

Java ,properties by default use ISO-8859-1, but nowadays there is IDE support for automatic u-escaping.

If you much with text searches / different text sources, consider a text *normalisation* using java.text.Normalizer. (`"ĉ"` can be two Strings: one code point SMALL_C_CIRCUMFLEX `ĉ` or SMALL_C `c` + zero-width COMBINING_DIACRITICAL_MARK_CIRCUMFLEX `^`)

The rest is framework dependent.